# Calling Login Screen javascript after postback?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-events

Working on my first MVC 4 app, and I'm having a problem with my login screen.  It is an intranet app for a company with common PCs on a manufacturing floor, so they need to be able to log in to the app on an individual basis.  (The site is also in jQuery mobile and has a Javascript touch keyboard, but I don't think they need be involved in this question)

The problem is that if someone fails to log in, the Javascript code that sets it so that enter key presses in the Username field send the focus to the Password field stops working.

I have a hack that works, (using setTimeout, 100) but it makes me feel icky and dirty.

Here's my LogOn form:

```
@ModelType FAToolAdmin.LogOnModel

@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Log In"
End Code


@Using Html.BeginForm()
    @<div class="content-primary">

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
            <h2>Account Info</h2>
        </div>
            
        <fieldset>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.UserName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.UserName)               
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Password)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.Password)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="notfocus"/>
            </p>

            @* This Html.ValidationSummary will show a ul element containing any login errors that were returned.  
                The call here has been edited to send an empty string, because sending 2 lines of text regarding 
                a login failure is a little excessive.  You failed to login.  Type everything again and move on 
                with your day.*@

            @Html.ValidationSummary(True, "")

        </fieldset>
    </div>

End Using

<script type="text/javascript">

    //This is the script that adds the keyboards to the screen.

    $(function () {
        //setTimeout(function () {

            //This is the script that makes it so that when the enter button is pressed on the screen that the 
            //focus is changed to the password box (rather than having the form be submitted).

            // set the focus to the UserName field and select all contents
            $('#UserName').focus().select();
            // bind the keypress event on the UserName field to this little piece of code here
            var $inp = $('#UserName');
            $inp.bind('keydown', function (e) {
                var key = e.which;
                // if this is keycode 13 (enter), then prevent the default form behavior and change focus to the Password box.
                if (key == 13) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    // find the Password input box and set the focus to it.
                    $('#Password').focus();
                }
            });
        //}, 100);
    });

</script>
```

and here's my controller:

```
Imports System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis
Imports System.Security.Principal
Imports System.Web.Routing

Public Class AccountController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    ' GET: /Account/LogOn
    <AllowAnonymous()>
    Public Function LogOn() As ActionResult
        Dim model As New LogOnModel
        Return View(model)
    End Function

    '
    ' POST: /Account/LogOn
    <AllowAnonymous()>
    <HttpPost()>
    Public Function LogOn(ByVal model As LogOnModel, ByVal returnUrl As String) As ActionResult
        Try
            If ModelState.IsValid Then

                If Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password) Then

                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, False)
                    If Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) AndAlso returnUrl.Length > 1 AndAlso returnUrl.StartsWith("/") _
                       AndAlso Not returnUrl.StartsWith("//") AndAlso Not returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\") Then
                        Return Redirect(returnUrl)
                    Else
                        Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
                    End If
                Else
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.")
                End If
            Else
                ' if you just click on login without ever having entered anything into the username and password fields, you'll get this message.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please enter a valid user name and password.")
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try

        ' If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        Return View(model)

    End Function

    '
    ' GET: /Account/LogOff
    <AllowAnonymous()>
    Public Function LogOff() As ActionResult
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
        Session.Abandon()
        Return (RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"))
    End Function

End Class
```

and model:

```
Public Class LogOnModel

    <Required()> _
    <Display(Name:="SomeCompany Username")> _
    Public Property UserName() As String

    <Required()> _
    <DataType(DataType.Password)> _
    <Display(Name:="Password")> _
    Public Property Password() As String

End Class
```

So my question is, how do I get it set up so that someone who types in a bad username (and hence triggers a `ModelState.AddModelError` and `Return View(model)`) is sent back to a version of the page where the enter press script has been loaded?

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental.  Appreciate any help someone can give.  Otherwise, `setTimeout` it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the jQueryMobile might be your problem - jqm uses ajax by default to submit all forms, so you're not getting a full postback.  I ran into a similar problem and that was the root cause.

Try using an overload for `Html.BeginForm` and add `new {data_ajax="false"}` to the HttpAttributes

Comment: That got it - Thanks! Replaced `@Using Html.BeginForm()` with `@Using Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account", Nothing, FormMethod.Post, New With {.data_ajax = "false"})`, and now everything behaves nicely.